# How could one derive power indicators for omnibus tests?

Tags: meta-analysis, statistical-power, post-hoc

A while ago I [posted a question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246534/is-it-uninformative-to-present-power-in-meta-analyses-after-the-fact) regarding performing post-hoc power analyses in meta-analyses and was given [a couple](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/193726/post-hoc-power-analysis-for-a-non-significant-result?rq=1) of [useful links](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Is_it_possible_to_calculate_the_power_of_study_retrospectively) to discussions regarding why this isn’t a good idea. From my reading of these discussions, and the suggested academic articles, one should rather than trying to do a post-hoc power analysis look at the confidence interval of the effect size of a null result to discern whether it contains an effect size that one would deem as relevant.

This is all well and good when having just a single effect size that isn’t significantly refuting the null hypothesis. However, how should one approach power indicators for omnibus tests of several effect sizes? For example, I might want to do a moderator analysis with two or more levels of a moderator, yielding an estimate and confidence interval for each moderator level. How can I in this case talk about the sensitivity of my test?

Comment: You can look at each moderator separately. I suppose that if you wanted to you could generate a confidence ellipse around two estimates, and so on into hyperspace.

Comment: @mdewey Thanks, I hadn't heard about confidence ellipses before. I'll check it out.